# How to update version of cordova intel xdk?

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I've an application developed in Inel XDK. It works fine but got a warning from google that they are deprecating the apps using cordova version < 4.1 in May 2016.

They also noted that there are some vulnerabilities with old versions of cordova. However I got time but want to make my app secure. I have checked the build preferences but haven't found any option there.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Go to projects->build settings->android->Cordova cli version-> change 3.5 to 4.1